# How to show/hide items from a select list based on another selection

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown

In JavaScript, how to show/hide items from a select list based on another selected option that contain a certain word or words?

I am very new to JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated.

There are two drop-downs: "group" and "alph".

```
<select name="group">
    <option value="Angry (Two)">Angry (Two)</option>
    <option value="Happy (Two)">Happy (Two)</option>
    <option value="Sad">Sad</option>
    <option value="Tired (One)">Tired (One)</option>
</select>

<select name="alph">
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="ABC-1">ABC-1</option>
    <option value="ABC-2">ABC-2</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="DEF-1">DEF-1</option>
    <option value="DEF-2">DEF-2</option>
    <option value="DEF-3">DEF-3</option>
</select>
```

Without IDs, for the first dropdown (name group), if the selected value contains " (Two)", then the list will only show:

```
<select name="alph">
    <option value="ABC-2">ABC-2</option>
    <option value="DEF-2">DEF-2</option>
</select>
```

If the user changes selection, and the selected value contains " (One)", then the list will only show:

```
<select name="alph">
    <option value="ABC-1">ABC-1</option>
    <option value="DEF-1">DEF-1</option>
</select>
```

If the user changes selection, and the selected value does not contain neither " (One)" or " (Two)", then the list will show:

```
<select name="alph">
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="DEF-3">DEF-3</option>
</select>
```

Note: I am not able to add IDs or attributes.  I can only access the name of the select and the value.

Comment: on both of the selects add `data-*` values such as `data-group="1"`, `data-group="2"`, etc. then hide the ones that don't match the current selected group.

Comment: Question for the select group. If there are 20+ options, rather using **data-*** for each one, is there a way to check if it contains **" (One)"** in the value then it will show **ABC-1** and **DEF-1**? If it contains **" (Two)"**, then show **ABC-2** and **DEF-2** etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-*` to create groups, then use a querySelector to get all the options and test if they are apart of the group or not. If they are apart of the group show them otherwise hide them.

```js
// The main group
let groups = document.querySelector('select[name=group]')

// Add a change event
groups.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // Get the currently selected Group
  let current = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex]
  // Get the data-group number
  let group = current.getAttribute('data-group')
  // Get all the items from the second dropdown
  let opts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select[name=alph]>option'))
  // Hide items that are not appart of the group
  opts.forEach(itm => itm.style.display = itm.getAttribute('data-group') == group || !itm.getAttribute('data-group') ? 'initial' : 'none')
  // Reset the the selection
  document.querySelector('select[name=alph]').selectedIndex = 0
})
```

```css
/* Hide option two items by default */
select[name=alph]>option[data-group]{display:none;}
```

```html
<select name="group">
    <option>Select One...</option>
    <option data-group="1" value="Angry (Two)">Angry (Two)</option>
    <option data-group="2" value="Happy (Two)">Happy (Two)</option>
    <option data-group="3" value="Sad">Sad</option>
    <option data-group="4" value="Tired (One)">Tired (One)</option>
</select>

<select name="alph">
    <option>Select One...</option>
    <option data-group="1" value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option data-group="1" value="ABC-1">ABC-1</option>
    <option data-group="2" value="ABC-2">ABC-2</option>
    <option data-group="2" value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option data-group="3" value="DEF-1">DEF-1</option>
    <option data-group="3" value="DEF-2">DEF-2</option>
    <option data-group="4" value="DEF-3">DEF-3</option>
</select>
```